# How can I stop user entering same value twice?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, input, menu

I'm asking the user to enter an integer between 1 and 10, but I want to make sure they don't enter the same value twice. How can I do this? Here is what I have so far...

```
cin >> input;
vector<int>val;
val.push_back(input);
for(int i=0; i<val.size(); i++){
if(input==val[i])
cout << "error";
exit(1);}
```

So this works in terms of terminating the program but it isn't useful because it always stops the program since input will be stored in val and it will find it through the loop and exit. Is there a way around this?
Alternatively I could make it so that the user cant enter the same value consecutively, but can input the same value more than once?

Comment: "sort of works". It totally works given your title: it will certainly stop the user from entering the same value twice. But it's apparently not what you want. What do you *do* want?

Comment: The code will never be useful becausr tbe code will exit even if no same numbers arw found, and even if it were not for `exit(1);`, the cide will detect the number jyst entered as duplicate.

Comment: @Amadan What I want is to not exit the program for any given input, which is what is happening since the if statement always runs true because input gets stored in val, found, then the loop tells the program to exit. I need the user to be able to enter any number once, but break when a number is entered more than once.

Comment: Then... replace the `exit` with `break`? (with some nice labeling; you need to break the correct loop).

Comment: It breaks fine, but the problem is it does it for any input. If I enter '1' then '2' and enter, it displays error message and exits, even though the user hasn't entered a value more than once.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see now. It would be better if you had wrote that in the OP (and indented the code properly). Simply don't push the `input` into the `val` until after you have checked the `val`.

Comment: Off topic: `exit` is a really hardcore way to exit a program. Everything stops and gets the heck out of Dodge right then and there. It doesn't slow down to clean up, so the stacks don't unroll, the destructors don't run, and stuff may not get put back where it's supposed to.

Comment: @Amadan thank you for that suggestion, it seems like it would work...I have tried it and now it never breaks the program. Hmm....

Answer (score 1):

If you indent your code properly, you might be able to see the solution.

```
cin >> input;
vector<int>val;
val.push_back(input);
for(int i=0; i<val.size(); i++){
   if(input==val[i])
      cout << "error";
   exit(1);
}
```

You want both

```
   cout << "error";
   exit(1);
```

to be executed when `input==val[i]`. Well... put both of them under that `if` statement.

```
   if(input==val[i])
   {
      cout << "error";
      exit(1);
   }
```

Comment: I have tried this already and it is not the solution, since input is immediately stored in val it finds it when looped, and exits even if the value is only entered once. This is what my issue is, not whether it exits when true but how to stop it being true for the first time the input is put in the vector. And FYI, in my compiler the code is indented.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the first element in your vector, the program will exit because the call to exit() isn't apart of the if statement that you have. To fix that, you would want to add curly braces to make it like:

```
if(input==val[i])
{
    cout << "error";
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is that the if statement is always true since the moment there is input it is stored in val, found and then the program exits!

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `input` and `val[i]` just in case? Something like `cout << "input: " << input << " val[i]: " <<val[i] << endl;`

Comment: Yes, val is being stored correctly. Lets say user inputs '1'. '1' goes to val, loop checks whats in val, sees '1' which is the same as input, so it exits.

Comment: So you don't want the program to exit whether or not the user has entered in the same value twice and want to ask the user to enter a value again if it already exists?

Comment: No I only want the program to exit if they enter a value more than once. If it helps, the numbers correlate to places to visit and it ruins some of the later parts of the program if two cities appear twice

Comment: That's because you used `val.push_back(input);` before the for loop. What you did was put `input` inside vector `val` and then compare `input` to all the values in the vector, which already contains `input`. Put the call after the for loop, here's an example: http://ideone.com/pWNSEV

Answer (score 1):

"Is there a way around this?" Yes, C++ is turing complete and it can do lots of things.

In this case, I guess you want something like this:

```
vector<int>val;
cin >> input;
bool err = false;
for(size_t i=0; i<val.size(); i++){
    if(input==val[i]){
        cout << "error";
        err = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!err) val.push_back(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do as it:

```
map<uint32_t, uint32_t> counter_map;
const uint32_t initial_counter = 0;
//create a counter
for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
{
    counter_map[i] = initial_counter;
}
int input;
while(cin >> input)
{
    if(input < 1 || input > 10)
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
        break;
    }

    ++counter_map[input];
    if(counter_map[input] > 1)
    {
        //input twice
        cout << "error" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

I hope this can help you.